# Storing HTML5 Geolocation information in MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've been experimenting with a simple project that essentially just stores the number of visits to the sites, along with the latitude / longitude of the user (it's mainly for people visiting via the iPhones Safari browser).

I've managed to store the 'clicks' to the page via PHP / MySQL, and I can display the users lat / long via the navigator.geolocation object in Javascript, but I have no idea how I can then store that (I'm fairly new at this!).

I appreciated that JavaScript is client-side and PHP is server-side, so I presume I need to somehow pass the returned values of my Javascript back to the PHP code somehow?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I'm not sure about it but it is possible to use HTML5 "Web Sockets" ? it is bi-directional client server & asynchrone data exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used the `navigator.geolocation` object, but you should be able to send what it returns to an external page using AJAX.

```
<script>
var data = 'something-here'; // the result of your geolocation call
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://yourdomain.com/storeLatLngInDb.php',
    data: data
});
</script>
```

The above is an example written on top of the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) framework.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's fairly clear on what I need to be doing.  I'll give your solution a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You presume well. You can either put them in hidden fields in a form and ask user to press the button to send data to serve, or you can initiate AJAX call.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid buttons where I can... Not to sound stupid, but like I say, I'm fairly new at this; what do you mean by initiating an AJAX call?  Could you give me some pointers as to what I should be looking at doing?